# jQuery Enable/Disable Text Selection Error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm actually trying to avoid text selection on double/triple clicks when users interact with dropdown elements (anchors without href attribute). This is the plugin I created:

```
.unselectable
{
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

;(function($)
{
    $.fn.disableSelection = function()
    {
        return this.each(function()
        {
            var element = $(this);
            element.addClass('unselectable');
            element.attr('unselectable', 'on');
            element.on('selectstart', false);
        });
    };

    $.fn.enableSelection = function()
    {
        return this.each(function()
        {
            var element = $(this);
            element.removeClass('unselectable');
            element.removeAttr('unselectable', 'on');
            element.on('selectstart', true);
        });
    };

})(jQuery);

$('#menu ul li a').click(function(e)
{
    var element = $(this);
    var target = $('#submenu_' + element.attr('class'));

    element.disableSelection();

    if (target.hasClass('hidden'))
    {
        target.hide();
        target.removeClass('hidden');
    }

    target.fadeToggle(300, 'swing');
    element.enableSelection();
});
```

I know those functions were deprecated in jQuery 1.9 blablabla, it doesn't really mind. Actually, everything works like a charm, really. But I keep on getting an error when the following line is processed:

```
element.on('selectstart', true);
```

And the console says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: ((n.event.special[g.origType] || (intermediate value)).handle || g.handler).apply is not a function
```

If I uncomment that line into the enableSelection function, the error doesn't appear anymore, and everything works like a charm but I really should make an effort to revert that event back to its original state because otherwise the element is misbehaving in other circumstances.

Do you know what's wrong with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function expects a function or `false` as the handler argument. While `false` is allowed as a shorthand for `function() { return false; }` the same is not true for `true`.

To enable selection again, remove the event handler with [`off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/).